# Poetry installing Numpy fails EnvCommandError for python 3.7 on m1 Mac

Tags: numpy, apple-m1, python-poetry

I have been trying to install Numpy in a poetry environment with python 3.7 installed on an M1 Mac, but have received the same EnvCommandError after trying many different solutions. I am still failing to build wheels and see a clang error about not supporting march flag -native. I will include the bottom of the resulting error message as well.

**Things I Have Tried**

- Rosetta booted terminal and installing with pip and x86 arch flag
- Rosetta booted terminal and installing with poetry
- Brew installing OPENBlas and running after setting path for OPENBlas
- Cloning Numpy and installing with no binary and no pep 517 flags
- Running with updated latest version of poetry

**Error Message**

```
Warning: attempted relative import with no known parent package
        /private/var/folders/g8/n76149jx1_s8bmqh02_lsmnh0000gp/T/pip-build-env-9yu5k12r/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/distutils/include -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/src/_simd -I/Users/maxnguyen/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/dataflow-ieQly66s-py3.7/include -I/Users/maxnguyen/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/include/python3.7m -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_unary_fp.dispatch.c -o build/temp.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/build/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_unary_fp.dispatch.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/build/src.macosx-12.2-arm64-3.7/numpy/core/src/umath/loops_unary_fp.dispatch.o.d -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
        [end of output]
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/utils/env.py:1195 in _run
      1191│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
      1192│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
      1193│                 )
      1194│         except CalledProcessError as e:
    → 1195│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
      1196│ 
      1197│         return decode(output)
      1198│ 
      1199│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already installed `openblas` (`brew install openblas`), try this:

`OPENBLAS="$(brew --prefix openblas)" poetry install`